# gremlin get all nodes which are directly or indirectly connected for a given node

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph, amazon-neptune

I'm newbie to gremlin.

I'm trying to get all nodes which are connected(directly or indirectly) to a given vertices. 
ex: 
one cluster like this in a graph.
A-D 
A-F 
F-B 
B-C 
B-G 
G-H 
G-I 

second cluster like this in a graph. 
J-k 
J-L

My Requirement when I search for the node "B", I need to get the all connected vertices for B (no edge direction) only. 
ex output: A,D,F,B,C,G,H,I

When I search for J.
ex outpu:J,k,L

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
g.V('B').emit().repeat(both().dedup()).toSet()
```

You basically traverse in both directions and emit every vertex you see until there's no new vertex found.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm able to retrieve this.

Comment: Thanks again, Will this work in huge number of edges also? like I have 500 million edges and 300 million vertices. How can I run the OLAP query for this? and store the results in hdfs/some file system. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In that case, you should consider using [ConnectedComponentVertexProgram](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#connectedcomponentvertexprogram) and have a look at [Interacting with Spark](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#interacting-with-spark).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I"m working on aws neptune, but this is not supporting the graph.traversal().withComputer() (OLAP) any idea how can I do this? i'm using apache-tinker pop 3.3.2.  As per the documentations AWS neptune supports OLAP service.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately, I've never worked with Neptune and I can't find any instructions on how to use OLAP.